# How to convert a symmetric matrix to pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

The following is a snippet of the symmetric matrix I have. I would like to convert this matrix into a pandas dataframe, to conduct data analysis on it.

```
       P62258 P61981 P31946 P63104 Q08380
P62258 100
P61981 69.23  100 
P31946 71.95  81.30  100
P63104 75.10  80.81  90.20  100
Q08380 7.45   8.50   7.31   8.16   100
```

The following is how I would like the dataframe to be.

```
Protein1  Protein2  Similarity
P62258    P62258    100
P61981    P62258    69.23
P31946    P62258    71.95
P63104    P62258    75.10
Q08380    P62258    7.45
P61981    P61981    100
P31946    P61981    81.30
.
.
.
```

Comment: kindly share your input dataframe as a dictionary : ``df.head().to_dict('list')``. Easier to reproduce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try

```py
out = (df.stack().dropna().reset_index()
       .rename(columns={'level_0': 'Protein1', 'level_1': 'Protein2', 0: 'Similarity'}))
# or
out = (df.stack().dropna().to_frame('Similarity')
       .rename_axis(index=['Protein1', 'Protein2'])
       .reset_index())
```

```
print(out)

   Protein1 Protein2  Similarity
0    P62258   P62258      100.00
1    P61981   P62258       69.23
2    P61981   P61981      100.00
3    P31946   P62258       71.95
4    P31946   P61981       81.30
5    P31946   P31946      100.00
6    P63104   P62258       75.10
7    P63104   P61981       80.81
8    P63104   P31946       90.20
9    P63104   P63104      100.00
10   Q08380   P62258        7.45
11   Q08380   P61981        8.50
12   Q08380   P31946        7.31
13   Q08380   P63104        8.16
14   Q08380   Q08380      100.00
```